# get data from server objective-c

Tags: php, objective-c, ios, http, nsurl

I have a problem getting data from the server. server is my localhost.

```
    SMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"localhost"] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData timeoutInterval:10.0];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"]; 
[request setHTTPBody:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"test.php"]];

NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self]; 
if (connection)
{
    NSLog(@"NSURLConnection connection==true");
    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSError *err;
    NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&err];
    NSLog(@"responseData: %@", responseData);
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"NSURLConnection connection==false");
};
```

on localhost I have simple php script called test.php:

```
    <?php
echo "It works!!!"
?>
```

If I'm opening localhost/test.php in safari I can see "It works!!!"

Comment: NSURLConnection connection==true
responseData: (null)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try @"http://localhost" instead of @"localhost"]

Comment: Yeah!!! Thanks. Now My response data is <3c3f7068 700a6563 686f2022 69742077 6f726b73 21212122 3b0a3f3e>

Comment: and save normally to NSString*

Comment: thats a different question but,   NSString *result = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];